# When we play several audio streams what is responsible for mixing them?

Tags: sound

When we play several audio streams what is responsible for mixing them in single audio playing via speakers?

Clearly it should be either OS combining the sounds or hardware getting multiple data streams.

Any references will be much appreciated.

Comment: [Hardware mixing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_mixing) is a thing. Some [software layers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture) support it. Other [software layers](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/) do the mixing themselves...

Comment: @Guest I think that comment, maybe enriched by a bit of text about the examples that you link to, would make a good answer :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller, if this question hasn't been close-voted into oblivion in a day or two, I'll do it :)